# Crystal report hidden filter mystery

Tags: c#, sql-server-profiler

I am new in crystal reports in c# and I try make a copy of some working crystal report. I copied database structure as well and filled it with my own data and my record selection is :

```
{TransactionsWithExtras.DocumentDate} >= {?DateFrom} AND
{TransactionsWithExtras.DocumentDate} <= {?DateTo} AND
({?ContactPointId} = '' OR {TransactionsWithExtras.ContactPointID} = {?ContactPointId})
```

The problem is:
 - when ContactPointId = '' shows values in crystal report
 - When ContactPointId is filled with some value, the crystal report
   shows nothing

When i try to run SQL script in Microsoft SQL Management Studio which i get in SQL Server Profiler from the request, it returns values.

I tried Verify Database in Crystal report and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
{TransactionsWithExtras.DocumentDate} >= {?DateFrom} AND
{TransactionsWithExtras.DocumentDate} <= {?DateTo} AND
(**ISNULL({?ContactPointId})** OR {TransactionsWithExtras.ContactPointID} =
     {?ContactPointId})
```

Hopefully this one works!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chris and AustinWBryan, i finally found the problem. I changed ContactPointId from uniqueidentifier to char(36) and its working.